# `npm run watch` not working in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.4 and Mix, when I run `npm run watch` it compiles everything once and looks like it is waiting for changes, but when I make changes to any of my asset files it doesn't seem to detect anything. Is there a solution?

Comment: Did you save your  file?

Comment: @mrabbani Yes the files are saved, but watch doesn't pick them up. If I stop watch and run it again it will find the changes on the first compile but nothing after that.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I run `npm run watch` and files are compiled only the first time. It seems that watch is waiting for changes but the only way to make it work is stop watch and run it again. Tried `node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch --watch-poll --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js` but still no luck.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The solution was provided by Jeffrey Way over at Laracasts.

Try adding the --watch-poll flag to your `package.json` script. Or just try:

`node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch --watch-poll --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`

Comment: FYI, as of May 3rd 2017, Laravel includes a 'watch-poll' command that does this for you.

Comment: `npm run watch-poll`

Comment: Webpack isn't present in `node_modules/.bin/` for me

Comment: This didnt work for me. `watch-poll` gave me the same results

Comment: The problem with this is it maxes out the processor making it very slow to work with. I don't suppose there is a fix for the actual issue?

Answer (score 13):

Use:

```
npm run watch-poll
```

It's working on Ubuntu as well. And it is auto compiling on code changes.

Answer (score 5):

> npm run watch-poll

`watch-poll` periodically checks (polls) for changes e.g. every 1000ms it will manually check to see if any files have changed.

what `laravel` docs say?

You may find that in certain environments Webpack isn't updating when your files change. If this is the case on your system, consider using the watch-poll command.
You can read up on the docs for a more information about [mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#running-mix).

Comment: It needs to be ***quoted***. Otherwise, it is [plagiarism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun). For example, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66137831/laravel-mix-watch-not-compiling-when-webpack-mix-js-updated/66138436#66138436).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [inotify-tools](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools).
To install this tool set, run this command:

[Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29):

```
sudo apt install inotify-tools -y
```

[CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS):

```
sudo yum -y install inotify-tools
```

Then for big folders, run:

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=500000000
```

Finally, run this command to watch folder changes:

```
while true; do npm run dev; inotifywait -e modify,create,delete,move -r resources/ ; done
```

You can limit the target watching directory (*resources/* in this example) for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `mix.scripts` which doesn't actually compile your scripts, just copies them, so there is no npm readout on a compilation, because it's not compiling anything. If you aren't using `mix.js` or `mix.sass` (r any of the other *compilers* in your `webpack.mix.js` file then `npm run watch` will appear to do nothing because it is just copying in the background.