# React js requires npm run dev command every time making changes in file

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I have integrated `react.js` with my `laravel` project . 
So I tried to change the file in `/components/Example.js`. 
But It is not showing the new change in the view page .
When I run

```
npm run dev
```

Only after run this command, the new changed component is showing in view file.
Do I need to run `npm run dev` for everytime making changes in `reactjs`?

Comment: Use `npm run watch --watch-poll` command after starting your developing and NPM will listen and re-build all your JS components on the fly after any changes

Comment: Do I need to keep it running in my terminal ? @RobinSingh

Comment: Yes of course otherwise it terminate your process

Comment: @RobinSingh Any other alternative for this ? What if I make any changes in my server ? Do I need to run `npm watch` in my server too?

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41866944/npm-run-watch-not-working-in-laravel-5-4)