# Laravel Mix 'watch' not compiling when webpack.mix.js updated

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

When I run `npm run watch` and update my source `.js` and `.scss` assets, the compilation is run automatically as expected. When I update the `webpack.mix.js` file, the changes are NOT compiled automatically.

Is this something that v6 doesn't support? Because v5 did work as expected.

The config:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix')

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/css/app.scss', 'public/css')
  .version()
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  ...

  "scripts": {
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "production": "mix --production"
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Did you tryied to stop the watch and run it again?

Comment: Yes. Also tried different OS's to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

Weird, it works for me. Try `npm run watch-poll` instead. You should be running the latest version of Laravel Mix:

```
"laravel-mix": "^6.0.11",
```

Unrelated, you may want to update your [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/) file to [the following](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/package.json) if you're using Laravel Mix 6.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
```

According to the 8.x Laravel documentation...

> Webpack may not be able to detect your file changes in certain local
> development environments. If this is the case on your system, consider
> using the watch-poll command.

Comment: That's basically my current setup.